# Create a dictionary with all functions from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have a file `functions.py` containing

```py
def some_function():
   return "something"

def some_other_function():
    return "something else"
```

I'm trying to create a dictionary in another file, `load_functions.py`, with keys being the function-names from `functions.py` and the items being the actual function e.g:

```py
import functions
useable_functions = [f for f in dir(functions) if "__" not in f] #Get all functions to be used
function_dict = TO_BE_IMPLEMENTED
print(function_dict)

#{"some_function":some_function,
#"some_other_function":some_other_function}

func = function_dict["some_function"]
func()
# "something"
```

Is it by all means doable?

Comment: Alternative to Icebreakers answer, you could always read `functions.py` as a file line by line and see if it contains `def ` and split it for functions name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the `inspect` module.

Say you have your `functions.py` module.
To get all functions from it, use this:

```py
import inspect

import functions  # your module

elements = inspect.getmembers(functions, inspect.isfunction)
element_dict = dict(elements)
```

The call will return all the function members of the `functions.py` module as a list of `(name, value)` pairs sorted by name. **Note** it will also include lambdas.

Then, I use `dict()` to convert the `(name, value)` pairs to a dict.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html